# Null Pointer Exception and Null Objects

Tags: grails, groovy, nullpointerexception

I have the following lines of code:

```
def edit = {
        if (session.user.id != params.id){
            flash.message = "You can only edit yourself."
            redirect(action:list)
            return
            }
        def user = User.get(params.id)
            if (!user){
                flash.message = "Login first before you edit anyone."
                redirect(action:list)
                }
            else{
                return [user:user]
                }
        }
```

I am fairly new to groovy and grails, so please get easy on me.
Anyways, the above code works only when a user has logged in into the site. 
When a user tries to edit something when he's not logged in, `User.get(params.id)` throws an exception. This in turn shows me the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id' on null object

    at com.hyun.UserController$_closure4.doCall(UserController.groovy:25)

    at com.hyun.UserController$_closure4.doCall(UserController.groovy)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The question is how do I properly handle this?  I believe the answer lies somewhere along these lines:

```
if (!user){
                flash.message = "Login first before you edit anyone."
                redirect(action:list)
                }
```

But I don't really know how to get about this. Please help me!
Flash.message isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe *Tomas Lycken* is right, try this instead:

```
if (session?.user?.id != params.id)
```

Further details on [safe navigation operator (?.)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator%28%3F.%29).

Comment: :D Thanks! I've been contemplating about using the elvis operator, haha! Solved my problem!

Comment: I just looked at this answer and used the safe navigation and it worked for my issue also

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on groovy or grails (I've actually never worked with either...), but I think the problem is that the first thing you do is check for `session.user.id` (in your first `if` clause). If the user is not logged-in, `session.user` probably returns `null`, which makes the call on `.id` throw the exception you see.